# What is the encoding of String value that is input from the keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, string, encoding, keyboard

I have the following code:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedString.string.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding))
mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body), range: range)
```

I need to know what string encoding to use where it says "String.Encoding" for the parameter "using" in the first line of the code above. The String object would always originate from the iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to create an `NSRange` to be used to add attributes, I don't believe `lengthOfBytes` is what you're looking for. Here a range represents a substring within your original `mutableAttributedString`, if you are simply looking to add an attribute to the whole string, your range should be defined as:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedString.string.count)
```

I'm otherwise not sure what you'd be using `lengthOfBytes` for, but I don't think that'll work for adding attributes as you seem to be doing here.